# Como escrever em um arquivo.json

Tags: java, android, json, mobile

Possuo alguns arquivos `.json` em `assets`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Atualmente estou fazendo apenas leitura nesses arquivos.

**Leitura**

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset(String Ajson) {
    String json = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(Ajson);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return json;
}
```

---

Como posso realizar escrita neles? Ou seja, substituir todo seu conteúdo por outro de minha escolha.

Answer (score 1):

Cristian,

O ideal mesmo seria você utilizar um JSON parser que facilitará a manipulação desse objeto modificado  do que simplesmente editar o texto do arquivo.

No site oficial você pode encontrar vários pacotes http://www.json.org/

Faça o download de um pacote, por exemplo: https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java

Importe para seu projeto e siga o exemplo de utilização:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

//instancia um novo JSONObject
JSONObject my_obj = new JSONObject();

//preenche o objeto com os campos: titulo, ano e genero
my_obj.put("titulo", "JSON Parser Exemplo");
my_obj.put("ano", 2017);
my_obj.put("genero", "Programação");
```

Assim ficará mais fácil a sua edição do seu json. Mais informações:

http://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-json-em-java-o-pacote-org-json/25480

---

Espero que isso ajude...

Boa Sorte!

Comment: Legal, mas preciso fazer isso pela linguagem Java, pois vou consumir de uma API o novo script json para substituir pelo antigo no arquivo que esta em assets.

Comment: Pegaria o novo json da API e colocaria esse json em uma String, substituiria o conteúdo existente no arquivo.json pelo conteúdo desta String.

Comment: Reformulei a resposta, te ajudou? Conseguiu fazer? Você gostaria também de saber o processo de escrita do json alterado? Abraço!